# Expanding in powers of a fraction

Tags: series-expansion

Is it possible to expand a function `f(x,y,z)` in powers of '`x/y`'?

I know how to expand in in powers of '`x`', but it is not a explicit function of 'x/y', as a result I can not do expansion by renaming '`x/y`' as a new variable and expand the function.

Any answers are highly appreciated.For example f could be as below:

```
(y+d)(1/z+ 6 x^2(z-z2)^2)/((z-z3)^2+4 x^2)^3/2
```

Comment: It is really complicated but, ok I will try to provide a simpler example @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: I've just added it @MariuszIwaniuk

Comment: I do not think this is possible in general. So e.g. (x+y) you want to expand as (x/y+1)y or what?

Comment: Yes, I think your expansion is correct @kiara

Answer (score 2):

A Proposal:  What about substituting r==x/y and r ->0

Test with known function  `g[x_, y_] = E^ArcTan[x/y - 1]`

```
(Series[E^ArcTan[r - 1], {r, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. r -> x/y // Expand

(*   E^(-Pi/4) + (E^(-Pi/4) x)/(2 y)   *)
```

Substituting x==r*y and y==x/r  yields the same result (expansion to second order).

```
(Series[g[r y , x/r ], {r, 0, 2}] // Normal) /. r -> x/y // 
    Simplify // Expand

(*   E^(-Pi/4) + (E^(-Pi/4) x)/(2 y)   *)
```

Now do the same with your function f

```
f[x_, y_] = (y + d) (1/z + 6 x^2 (z - z2)^2)/((z - z3)^2 + 4 x^2)^3/2
```

**Edit: Variable r instead of z, since z is already in the function**

```
(Series[f[r y, x/r], {r, 0, 0}] // Normal) // Simplify // Expand

(*   d/(2 z (z - z3)^6) + x/(2 r z (z - z3)^6)   *)
```

Backsubstitution for zero order

```
(Series[f[r y, x/r], {r, 0, 0}] // Normal) /. r -> x/y // FullSimplify

(*   (d + y)/(2 z (z - z3)^6)   *)
```

first order

```
(Series[f[r y, x/r], {r, 0, 1}] // Normal) // Simplify // Expand

(*   -((6 r x y^2)/(z (z - z3)^8)) + d/(2 z (z - z3)^6) + 
      x/(2 r z (z - z3)^6) + (3 r x y^2 z^2)/(z - z3)^6 - 
      (6 r x y^2 z z2)/(z - z3)^6 + (3 r x y^2 z2^2)/(z - z3)^6   *)
```

Or r backsubstituted

```
(Series[f[r y, x/r], {r, 0, 1}] // Normal) /. r -> x/y // FullSimplify

(*  (6 x^2 y (-2 + z (z - z2)^2 (z - z3)^2) + (d + y) (z - z3)^2)
     /(2 z (z - z3)^8)   *)
```

Comment: Note that I have z in my function and the way you used may leads to mistake

Comment: Oh, I didn't notice. I just correct my answer.

Comment: I defined `f[x_, y_] = (y + d) (1/z + 6 x^2 (z - z2)^2)/((z - z3)^2 + 4 x^2)^3/2 `. Now comes the substitution `r==x/y `and therfore `x==r*y` and `y==x/r`. Exactly what I then applied  `f[x,y]`  becomes `f[r y, x/r]` under the substitution.